# Google Contacts API v3 parameter for multiple search terms

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am trying to search multiple terms in Google contacts API using JS. When I try with single term it is working fine. Here is the code used for single term.

```
gapi.client.request({
    method: 'GET',
    path: 'm8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q=TERM&alt=json',
    headers: {
            "GData-Version": "3.0",
            "if-match":"*",
            "data":token,
        },
  callback: function(response) {
     console.log(response);
   }
});
```

For multiple terms, I am using the following codes "q=TERM1 TERM2" or "q=TERM1+TERM2" or "q=TERM1%20TERM2" but it is not working. I got 0 contacts matched for this search.

I have followed "standard query parameters" as in this link https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference. I knew it is v2 document, but still it is connected with v3 document https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#ProjectionsAndExtended. Please advice what I did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: note that the values in `q=` are AND'ed together, not OR'ed. Are you sure the contact has both of the terms? Also, out of curiosity, which fields are the terms in?

Comment: Thank you Blake. Its my mistake that I thought it was OR. Is it possible to search as "OR" instead of "AND"? and also search in a particular field like "address" instead of searching globally. Please advice.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. You'll have to do post-processing on your query request(s) to get these sorts of fine-tuned results.